# "Having" vs "Being in" a fight

Tags: verbs, word-usage

I was reading some articles on the Internet when I came across this sentence:

> I was being in a fight with him.

Is using "being in a fight" correct, or does it need to be changed to "having a fight"?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "I was being in a fight with him" sounds odd to me: I certainly wouldn't say it even though I think that it's  _grammatically_ correct. Much more normal are: "I was in a fight with him," "I was having a fight with him", "I was fighting him" and "He and I were fighting". To be honest "I was being in a fight with him" sounds like an Irish turn of phrase to me.

Comment: It depends on the context.

Answer (score 1):

They area largely equivalent but the phrase "Being in a fight" has a currency that cannot be discounted. It refers to a vital, current (or eternal) struggle that must be won at all costs. The sentence refers to the feeling of having lost without even the satisfaction of effort to prove one's potential. "At least you tried." is the corresponding sobriquet. Correcting the grammar is adding insult to injury.

Considering the edited question, yes. If there is no special, story telling, meaning to the description then, "having a fight with him" would be the correct grammar.

Comment: Please see the edited version of the question.

Comment: Correcting the grammar... - But what happens in reality is that itself, isn't it?